# Find the values of the parameters $A$ and $\phi$ such that $\begin{aligned}\cos t+\sqrt{3}\sin t=A\sin(t+\phi)\end{aligned}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the values of the parameters $A$ and $\phi, $ with $A> 0$ and $0\leqslant \phi< 2\pi, $ such that
> $\begin{aligned}\cos t+\sqrt{3}\sin t=A\sin(t+\phi)\end{aligned}$
> for all real values of $t.$

My first idea was to expand $\cos t+\sqrt{3}\sin t=A(\sin t \cos \phi + \cos t \sin \phi)$, but I am not sure what to do next?

Comment: Solve the system $A\cos\phi=\sqrt3$, $A\sin\phi=1$. Hop to it!

Comment: You can eliminate $A$ from the system by dividing both sides. And you can eliminate $\phi$ by using $\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi=1$. And search the site. This is a standard exercise, and I'm sure we have done similar problems many times. Quite likely this exact variant as the required numbers fit into standard triangles.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, can you tell how you got $A\cos \phi = \sqrt{3}$ and $A \sin \phi = 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(t + \phi) = \sin t \cos \phi + \cos t \sin \phi$

$\sin(t + \phi) = \frac{1}{A} \cos t + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{A} \sin t$

Hence:

$\sin \phi = \frac{1}{A}$

$\cos \phi = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{A}$

As $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$, you might understand that $\frac{1}{A^2} + \frac{3}{A^2} = 1$, meaning that $A= \pm 2$. The rest is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos t+\sqrt{3} \sin t = & 2\left(\frac{1}{2} \cos t+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin t\right) \\
= & 2\left(\sin \frac{\pi}{6} \cos t+\cos \frac{\pi}{6} \sin t\right) \\
= & 2 \sin \left(t+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\\ \therefore A=&2 \text { and } \phi=\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$